# Struct passed by reference results in garbage values

Tags: c++

Going through Project Euler and working through what I thought was a simple problem.  For some reason when passing a struct Date by reference it results in garbage values when I try to reference or assign them.  Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    // century 
    if ((year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))
        return true;
    // not a century
    else if ((year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0))
        return true;

    return false;
}

enum Months {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC};

struct Date
{
    int year;
    Months month;
    int day;
};

int calculateNumberOfDays(const Date& begin, const Date& end)
{
    int numberOfDays = 0;

    //PROBLEM: This loop never runs... Upon running it through the debugger
    //         the value of year is garbage i.e. -859382918
    //         This results in the loop not being entered and the value 
    //         (numberOfDays) being returned as 0
  for (int year = begin.year; year < end.year; year++)
    {
        if (isLeapYear(year))
            numberOfDays += 366;
        else
            numberOfDays += 365;
    }

    //TODO: Finish for final year

    return numberOfDays;
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfDays = 0;
    int year = 1900;
    Months month = JAN;
    int day = 1;


    Date begin = { 1990, JAN, 1 };
    Date end = { 1901, DEC, 31 };

    cout << calculateNumberOfDays(begin, end) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it contains 1 as it should.

Comment: Are you using VS2015?  It's resulting in garbage values for me.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? For example, `isLeapYear` function is missing. I suspect the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Updated with the rest of the code.

Comment: I just ran this updated code (using gcc 5.3.1) and I also get 1 for begin.day (and year).

Comment: Where are you getting the garbage value in the code? could you simply print the value where you've written problem?

Comment: I've run it through a debugger and cout'ed the value of year after it's been assigned and I keep getting a garbage value. Something makes me think it's a bug in VS2015. When year is set to 0 it indicates correctly. However, when I set it to begin.year and then check the value it is garbage.

Comment: I can't reproduce the garbage values, but in your` calculateNumberofDays `function, you define` int year = 0; year = begin.day;` and then in the next loop you declare` int year = begin.year;`. That's just weird, make the names not match.

Comment: @DeiDei I know that. I was just doing it for testing. It won't affect it.

Comment: In the VS debugger, stepping over the "year = begin.day" line shows year with a value of 0xcccccccc (-858993460), but then the value is shadowed by the declaration of "int year" on the next line, so I suspect it's just the compiler being too smart for itself.

Comment: Why is this even a problem if it just shows in the debugger? Just remove the two lines `int year=0; year=begin.day;`. This variable `year` is never used again.

Comment: @KarstenKoop how is it not a problem?  It isn't just the debugger. It does it when running. And the reason it matters is because the for loop that actually relies on that variable does not run.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @KarstenKoop and just because that may work in that case doesn't mean there isn't a bug somewhere. It's not okay for a compiler to just assign garbage values when the object passed in does not have garbage values.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I'd love to help you with this problem but can't because you have not documented any observable behavior with this program that is incorrect. What output did you get? What output did you expect? I ran this and got 0. Did I replicate your problem or not?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I updated for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `begin` date is after your `end` date, so the loop doesn't run. Swapping the two dates causes the loop to run correctly.

Your debugger is likely getting confused because you have two variables called `year`. That sent you down the wrong path.

Comment: I must be missing something... My begin date is before my end date.

Comment: @keelerjr12 I'm sorry, but the year 1990 is after the year 1901 in the Gregorian calendar

Comment: Do you agree that your start year is 1990 and your end year is 1901?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Wow, numbers... they matter... Sorry for wasting your time with a typo.  Thank you for spotting that. Should be 1900!